# Replace ID to an element for a particular url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have two list items in navigation:

```
<body id="trips">
   <nav>
      <li><a href="/trips.php" class="trips">Trips</a></li>
      <li><a href="/trips.php?offer=true" class="offers">Offers</a></li>
   </nav>
   ....
</body>
```

I need to replace on `<body id="trips">`  with `<body id="offers">` when visiting **/trip.php?offer=true** because I am using CSS to make current page:

```
#trips.trips, #offers.offers { css for "current page" button }
```

Any idea? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you need to add this in `trips.php`

```
<?php
   $bodyID = 'trips'; // default value
   // when `offer` GET is set
   if(isset($_GET['offer']) && trim($_GET['offer']) == 'true'){
      $bodyID = 'offers';
   }
?>
<body id="<?php print $bodyID; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can add script inside `body` tag, which will set needed id.

```
<script>
  document.body.id = location.href.split('?')[1].contains('offer=true');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using PHP, you could determine if the GET variable for offer is set to true, and set an id variable accordingly:

```
if(isset($_GET['offer'])) { # If the GET variable is set
    if($_GET['offer'] == "true") { # If the GET variable is equal to true
        $id = "offers"; # Set our ID equal to offers
    }
}
else { # If the GET variable is not set
    $id = "trips"; # Set our ID equal to trips
}
```

You'd then have HTML with the following:

```
<body id="<?php if(isset($id)) { print $id; } ?>">
```